# Neo4j Cypher - Query partial fixed route and partial variable route

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have a graph network like shown here:
[image: Graph Network]

I can do a cypher query using something like

```
MATCH (a:A)-[]->(b:B)-[]->(c:C)-[]-(d1:D),
(a)-[]->(b)-[]->(c)-[]-(d2:D),
(a)-[]->(b)-[]->(c)-[]-(d3:D),
(a)-[]->(b)-[]->(c)-[]-(d4:D),
WHERE d1.val = '1' AND d2.val = '2' AND d3.val ='3', d4.val = '4'
RETURN a, b, c, d1, d2, d3, d4
```

Is there a way to simplify this query, without explicitly rewriting the relationship over and over again, which are identical. I am trying to find every relation which has all the `D` values I am expecting, which is large list so probably an `IN` clause would be appropriate.

Edit:
Sample data based on answer below

```
create (a1:A {name: 'A1'})
create (b1:B {name: 'B1'})
create (c1:C {name: 'C1'})
create (d1:D {name: 'D1', val: 1})
create (d2:D {name: 'D2', val: 2})
create (d3:D {name: 'D3', val: 3})
create (d4:D {name: 'D4', val: 4})
create (a1)-[:NEXT]->(b1)
create (b1)-[:NEXT]->(c1)
create (c1)-[:NEXT]->(d1)
create (c1)-[:NEXT]->(d2)
create (c1)-[:NEXT]->(d3)
create (c1)-[:NEXT]->(d4)
create (a2:A {name: 'A2'})
create (b2:B {name: 'B2'})
create (c2:C {name: 'C2'})
create (a2)-[:NEXT]->(b2)
create (b2)-[:NEXT]->(c2)
create (c2)-[:NEXT]->(d1)
create (c2)-[:NEXT]->(d2)
create (a3:A {name: 'A3'})
create (b3:B {name: 'B3'})
create (c3:C {name: 'C3'})
create (a3)-[:NEXT]->(b3)
create (b3)-[:NEXT]->(c3)
create (c3)-[:NEXT]->(d1)
create (c3)-[:NEXT]->(d2)
create (c3)-[:NEXT]->(d3)
create (c3)-[:NEXT]->(d4)
return *
```

So the query should result in `A1-->B1-->C1-->D1,D2,D3,D4` and `A3-->B3-->C3-->D1,D2,D3,D4`
Since `A2-->B2--C2` links with only `D1,D2` and not `D3,D4` it should not be in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beginning of the path is always the same, so you don't need to repeat it. Then, based on a list of values, you want to check if you can find a `D` for each and every one of them: it could be a job for [`all`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#functions-all).

Mixing all that, we get:

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)-->(d:D)
WHERE d.val IN {values}
WITH a, b, c, collect(d) AS dList
WHERE all(value IN values WHERE any(d IN dList WHERE d.val = value))
RETURN a, d, c, dList
```

However, if *n* is the number of values, that's an O(n^2) algorithm because of the second `WHERE`.

Let's collect the values of the nodes while collecting the nodes themselves, to avoid the double loop and turn it into a O(n) algorithm:

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)-->(d:D)
WHERE d.val IN {values}
WITH a, b, c, collect(d) AS dList, collect(DISTINCT d.val) AS dValues
WHERE all(value IN values WHERE value in dValues)
RETURN a, d, c, dList
```

Assuming the list of values passed as a parameter only contains distinct values, we can even change that into an O(1) algorithm by simply comparing the size of the input list and the distinct values found:

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)-->(d:D)
WHERE d.val IN {values}
WITH a, b, c, collect(d) AS dList, collect(DISTINCT d.val) AS dValues
WHERE size({values}) = size(dValues)
RETURN a, d, c, dList
```

Because `dValues ⊂ values`, if the 2 sets have the same size, they're equal.

If `D.val` are globally unique, or at least unique for all the `D` nodes connected to a single `C`, it can be further simplified:

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)-->(d:D)
WHERE d.val IN {values}
WITH a, b, c, collect(d) AS dList
WHERE size({values}) = size(dList)
RETURN a, d, c, dList
```

If the values are globally unique, the query will be faster with the unicity constraint as it will also index the values:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (d:D) ASSERT d.val IS UNIQUE
```

Answer (score 2):

If every `D` node has a unique `val` property (if any), this should work:

```
WITH [1,2,3,4] AS desired

MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)-->(d:D)
WHERE d.val IN desired
WITH a, b, c, COLLECT(DISTINCT d) AS ds
WHERE SIZE(ds) = SIZE(desired)
RETURN a, b, c, ds
```

The result will have a row for every matched `A`, `B`, `C` combination, along with the collection of `D` nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following data set...

```
create (a:A {name: 'A'})
create (b:B {name: 'B'})
create (c:C {name: 'C'})
create (d1:D {name: 'D1', val: 1})
create (d2:D {name: 'D2', val: 2})
create (d3:D {name: 'D3', val: 3})
create (d4:D {name: 'D4', val: 4})
create (a)-[:NEXT]->(b)
create (b)-[:NEXT]->(c)
create (c)-[:NEXT]->(d1)
create (c)-[:NEXT]->(d2)
create (c)-[:NEXT]->(d3)
create (c)-[:NEXT]->(d4)
return *
```

You could execute a query something like this to match all of the specific `D` nodes in a particular value range.

```
match (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)-->(d:D)
where d.val in range(1,4)
return *
```

Here is an updated query based on your updated question. I collected the `D` values for each `A,B,C` chain of nodes.

```
match (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)-->(d:D)
where d.val in range(1,4)
with a, b, c, d
order by a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name
return a, b, c, collect(d) as d
order by a.name, b.name, c.name
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include modified version of your create statement. I'm looking for relation which has all expected D values from my list.